# Como faço para receber o valor de $_GET de uma URL no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou enviando um valor `get` através de um link por exemplo:

```
<a href="/admin/editar_user/5">Editar</a>
```

E lá no método do meu controller que chama a view eu recebo:

```
public function editar_user(){
    $this->load->view('admin/editar_user');
}
```

Até aqui ele está chamando a view do jeito que eu queria, mas quero saber como pego aquele valor enviado via `get` que nesse caso seria `5`

por exemplo:

```
public function editar_user(){
        // comando pegar valor get  5
        $this->load->view('admin/editar_user');
    }
```

Como pego o valor `get`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe:

## [URI Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

> The URI Class provides functions that help you retrieve information
>   from your URI strings. If you use URI routing, you can also retrieve
>   information about the re-routed segments.

Basicamente ela auxilia você a recuperar os segmentos de uma URL.

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

Onde `n` é o número do segmento que deseja retornar.

## [Passagem de parâmetros no Controller](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)

Exemplo de URL:

```
site.com.br/index.php/produtos/sapatos/tipo/123
```

*Controller*

```
<?php
class Produtos extends CI_Controller {
    public function sapatos($tipo, $id)
    {
        echo $tipo;
        echo $id;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Valeu, estou fazendo uns testes quando funcionar eu te dou o certo :)

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha Faz tempo que não uso CI, acredito que seja isso. Mas tenho uma certa paixão por ser meio primeiro framework. rs

Comment: Ok... funcionou

Answer (score 7):

se você estiver usando 
assim: site.com.br/index.php/produtos/sapatos/tipo/123
será um parametro no controller
criando o método assim:

```
public function sapatos($tipo, $id){
    echo $tipo;
    echo $id;
}
```

se usar a url assim:
assim: site.com.br/index.php/produtos/sapatos/?tipo=1&id=123

 O metodo tem que ficar assim:

```
public function sapatos(){
    echo $this->input->get('tipo'); // recupera a informação via get
    echo $this->input->get('id');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No `editar_user()` defina um argumento por exemplo `$id`, quando o usuário clicar no link o valor `5` será atribuido a `$id`

```
public function editar_user($id){
        echo $id;
        $this->load->view('admin/editar_user')
}
```